# Angular 5 InMemoryDbService collection not working

Tags: angular, typescript, mocking, angular5

I'm using the InMemoryDbService as shown in the tour of heroes sample Angular app. It works well, and even in my own project, until I attempt to do something 'fancy' like adding in an embedded object.

In the createDb method, this way works:

```
const my_search = [
    {
        'id': 555,
        'firstName': 'fred',
        'lastName': 'flintstone'
    }
]
```

but this way doesn't work (extraData object included):

```
const my_search = [
{
  'id': 555,
  'firstName': 'fred',
  'lastName': 'flintstone',

  'extraData' :{
    'extrathingie':'hi'
    }          
   }

}
]
```

I don't get any errors in the backend, but the UI complains about undefined coming thru. Is this even possible? 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to quote the keys.

Answer (score 1):

The second Object is not write, try this:

```
const my_search = [{
    'id': 555,
    'firstName': 'fred',
    'lastName': 'flintstone',

    'extraData': {
        'extrathingie': 'hi'
     }
}]
```